# How do I show that all logical formulas have more statement variables than binary connectives

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

The binary connectives in predicate logic are ∧, ∨ and →. How do I show that all logical formulas have more statement variables than binary connectives (several occurrences of the same variable or the same connective count count several times; ie ((P ∧ Q) ∧ R) has three statement variables and two binary connectives - each).

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. If you [edit] the question to show us how you started and where you are stuck you are more likely to get help rather than downvotes or votes to close. Hint: can two connectives be adjacent?

Comment: By induction: *base case* - an atomic formula has 1 statement variables and 0 binary connectives.

Comment: *Induction step*: obvious.